# Get Service name from code

Tags: c#, service

Hi All am trying to get current service name from my project installer i have added a basic installer to my service application and wrote my service name and Display name but i need to get the service name from code

i have tried to add method in project installer then call it but it does not work :<

```
public static string getname()
{
    return ProjectInstaller1.ServiceName;
}
```

my error:=

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'myservice.ProjectInstaller.ProjectInstaller1'

Comment: Can you post code for your class? It appears that ProjectInstaller1 is not static.

Comment: can you get the service name from the .config file based on the key name..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're insisting on the `public static string getname()` definition, this *should* work:

```
//assuming ProjectInstaller1 can be instantiated
return new ProjectInstaller1().ServiceName;
```

Comment: I can't help but think that you've made the world worse by solving this particular problem.

Comment: could you have done it in an easier fashion String servcName = this.ServiceName;

Comment: @PrestonGuillot:  Indeed but I can only imagine so much with the code in question (but I am inclined to side with you on it).  It's part of the reason I added the _If you're insisting on..._ clause.